# Djnago Login level

Tags: django, django-login

I have three types of user and each use have different dashboard means three level admin manager and operation team but i want if user is of type admin enter the admin dasbhboard and if the user is manager then enter manager dashboard and if the user is of employee enter in to respective dashboard in django want to create

Comment: awesome so whats stopping you creating it.

Comment: just create user model and and user_type field that's all

Answer (score 0):

In your view, you can access `request.user` and from that  deduce the type of user. You can then do whatever is needed to show the right thing for a user of that type.

Redirecting to the appropriate one of `admin_dashboard_view`, `manager_dashboard_view` or `employee_dashboard_view` might be the way to go, with a simple permission test at the top of each of those views to raise an error if the user in `request.user`  is not authorized to be accessing that view.

You should bear in  mind that a manager or admin is probably also an employee. The above design can handle this -- the top or default  view simply dispatches to a default, so a manager can see his employee view byexplicitly  explicitly going to the employee view URL. An employee who tries for the manager view will get an error message.